# SQL - Advance Comparison between 2 tables using "IS LIKE"

Tags: sql-server

Ok this is going to get a bit chaotic so please try to stay with me..

I got a table of information kind of like this...

```
Table Name: Customers
_____________________________
ID   | CompanyName | FirstName | LastName  | Phone
-------------------------------
1    | Joes        | Joe       | James     | 1233334444
2    | Kennys      | Kenny     | Johnson   | 2222334555
3    | Kellys      | Kelly     | Gibson    | 5454445445
4    | Ricks #1    | Rick      | Lawson    | 4545334222
5    | Johns #1    | Johny B   | James     | 4545222211
6    | Johns #2    | Johny     | James     | 4545222211
7    | Johns #3    | Johny     | James     | 4545222211
8    | Ricks #2    | Rick A    | Lawson    | 4545334222
```

I need to know how to create an SQL statement that finds all the duplicate records, adds them up, then displays the total amount of duplicates found with the first company name found.

*HERE's THE CATCH - As you see from the table above, sometimes they put their initials with their name (Example - ID5 and ID6 are the same exact person, but he put his middle initial in ID5, you can see the same with ID4 and ID7)

I need the SQL statement to base the comparison off first matching the lastname, then doing a "IS LIKE" on the first name and company name "kind-of-thing" to make sure that they are being counted as they should be.

For Example - I should get a result similar to...

```
Table Name: TableResults
_____________________________
ID   | CompanyName | FirstName | LastName  | Phone       | Count
-------------------------------
4    | Ricks #1    | Rick      | Lawson    | 4545334222  | 2
5    | Johns #1    | Johny B   | James     | 4545222211  | 3
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need to use fuzzy matching.

Try this:

```
WITH InitialData AS
(
  SELECT *, SOUNDEX(LastName) + SOUNDEX(CompanyName) Similarity 
    FROM Customers
), FinalData AS
(
  SELECT *, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Similarity ORDER BY ID) Position,
          COUNT(1)  OVER(PARTITION BY Similarity) Count
  FROM InitialData
)
SELECT ID, CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Count
  FROM FinalData
WHERE Position = 1
  AND Count > 1
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c1fb/2

Comment: Uh, how do i use that in SQL? I've tried copy 'n paste and i just get errors. I just get "invalid SQL statement"

Comment: The code I posted is SQL. What are the errors? What is the Version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: I've tried that in both SQL 2005 and Access 2007. Both say Invalid SQL statement

Comment: apparently i copied 'n pasted wrong into SQL server 2005. So i guess there's no way to do this for Access?

Comment: Am not sure if there is any inherent method in Access for Fuzzy matching. But you can check this article to add one: http://allenbrowne.com/vba-Soundex.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe the name analysis will be some really complicated SQL, if it's possible at all.  First off, you may want to make sure your name columns use a Case-*insensitive* collation such as `utf8_general_ci`.  I wouldn't trust people to consistently capitalize their names.  They may also have typo's if they're being careless.

`LIKE` isn't smart enough to match on strings that have small differences unless you know exactly where to put the `%`.  It's more just a wildcard matching function.

Maybe check out using a [SOUNDEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) algorithm? But this will only work if all of your data will be in English.

Is the Phone number a reliable way to identify duplicates?  If so, you could skip the name analysis and just do this:

```
SELECT ID, CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Phone, COUNT(1) AS Count
FROM Customers 
GROUP BY Phone
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: No sometimes they list different phone numbers so i can't use phone number